# Android add my app to "Share" button in gallery

Tags: java, android, share

I succeed to add my app in the "share" button in the Android gallery, so if I click on it, my app will start. Can I choose which activity of my app to start? 
Now it starts the "main" one. Here's my code in the main class:

```
    .....        
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    // if this is from the share menu
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {   
        if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            // Get resource path
        }
    }
```

And the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

In reality I succeed in opening a new activity immediately after the "main" starts but I'll prefer to directly open the right one.
Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put your intent filter under activity you want to start into your manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".Theme"
           android:label="MAIN">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>

 <activity android:name=".Theme"
           android:label="ActiVITY2">
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: @jaumard hey your answer helps me, but i want the image which i want to share in an imageview in one activity. How can i do this ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller use : Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); for a single image, or use  ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); for multiple images

Comment: this method is just for image in gallery ,not working on video in gallery,when I change image/* to video/* still not working.

Comment: works fine. but opens another instance of the app. is there any solution for this?

Comment: Android Application are singleton, so it's not possible to launch another instance of the app. Another instance of the activity yes if you want to use a current instance of the activity or create add the Intent Flag like FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Comment: To receive multiple images: `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />`

Comment: this doesn't work when I share image from filemanager any help?

Answer (score 6):

If you had two activities in your manifest file, say `Main` and `MediaShare` then it would look something like this:

```
<activity android:name="Main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="MediaShare" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The `android.intent.action.SEND` action and `android:mimeType="image/*"` data should go with the activity you want to start when you share an image.

See the [page on Receiving Content from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) for more details.

Comment: To receive multiple images: `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />`