# camera captured image share to different application

Tags: android, android-camera, share

> I am working on a application in which there a part of taking images
>   from camera and have to share images to the different applications . I am using a code but it is not sharing the images. please have a look and please tell where I am wrong.

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);

        click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

            }
        });

        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable();

                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

                // Save this bitmap to a file.
                File cache = getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();
                File sharefile = new File(cache, "toshare.png");
                try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sharefile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                // Now send it out to share
                Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + sharefile));
                try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share photo"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
        });
    }
         protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                    //2
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                    image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    //3
                    share.setVisibility(0);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                    //4
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        //5
                        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                        fo.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

           }
         }

  }
```

Comment: `Uri.parse("file://" + sharefile)` try with `Uri.parse("file://" + sharefile.getAbsolutePath())` instead. And tell exactly what happened as you didn't do that. What does the user see?

Comment: @greenapps :- nothing happened, it is not sharing the image... also i m not getting any error in logcat too.. :(

Comment: Nothing happens? Tell exactly what the user does and sees. And did you check with a file explorer (like ES FileExplorer) if the image is created in that folder? How far does your code flow? And tell what is exactly the value of getAbsilutePath(). And tell which part of your code is executed and which part not.

Comment: @greenapps after capturing the image, I pressed share button. it gives application options so I can choose anyone like watsapp, facebook, mail etc to share that image.. when I choose any option it opens the respective application and asks me "you want to share with XYZ". When I press "yes" it returns the control to the camera layout without sharing the image.

Comment: Ok. Thats better. But i requested more info. Please give that info.

Comment: `it returns the control to the camera layout` That i do not understand. The camera is already longtime closed i think and you started from your app with that send intent. So it returns to your app.

Comment: Reference link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609458/android-add-my-app-to-share-button-in-gallery

Comment: @RIT he asked for something else.

Comment: @greenapps control 1) start camera and capture the image.
 control 2) display the captured image in imageview and a share button is there to share it. 
when I trying to share it, it goes back to the control 2 and again you can see imageview and share button.

Comment: `And did you check with a file explorer (like ES FileExplorer) if the image is created in that folder? How far does your code flow? And tell what is exactly the value of getAbsilutePath(). And tell which part of your code is executed and which part not. `